# Performing Aggregation of records and launch spring cloud task in single Processor in Spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to perform the following actions

1. Aggregating messages
2. Launching Spring Cloud Task
   But not able to pass the aggregated message to the method launching Task. Below is the piece of code

```
    @Autowired
    private TaskProcessorProperties processorProperties;

    @Autowired
    Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    private AppConfiguration  appConfiguration ;


    @Transformer(inputChannel = MyProcessor.intermidiate, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Object setupRequest(String message) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.processorProperties.getDataSourceUrl())) {
            properties.put("spring_datasource_url", this.processorProperties.getDataSourceUrl());
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.processorProperties.getDataSourceDriverClassName())) {
            properties.put("spring_datasource_driverClassName", this.processorProperties
                    .getDataSourceDriverClassName());
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.processorProperties.getDataSourceUserName())) {
            properties.put("spring_datasource_username", this.processorProperties
                    .getDataSourceUserName());
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(this.processorProperties.getDataSourcePassword())) {
            properties.put("spring_datasource_password", this.processorProperties
                    .getDataSourcePassword());
        }
        properties.put("payload", message);

        TaskLaunchRequest request = new TaskLaunchRequest(
                this.processorProperties.getUri(), null, properties, null,
                this.processorProperties.getApplicationName());
        System.out.println("inside task launcher  **************************");
        System.out.println(request.toString() +"**************************");
        return new GenericMessage<>(request);
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT,outputChannel = MyProcessor.intermidiate)
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler aggregator() {
        AggregatingMessageHandler aggregatingMessageHandler =
                new AggregatingMessageHandler(new DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor(),
                        new SimpleMessageStore(10));
        AggregatorFactoryBean aggregatorFactoryBean = new AggregatorFactoryBean();
        //aggregatorFactoryBean.setMessageStore();
        //aggregatingMessageHandler.setOutputChannel(processor.output());
        //aggregatorFactoryBean.setDiscardChannel(processor.output());
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendPartialResultOnExpiry(true);
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setSendTimeout(1000L);
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setCorrelationStrategy(new ExpressionEvaluatingCorrelationStrategy("'FOO'"));
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setReleaseStrategy(new MessageCountReleaseStrategy(3)); //ExpressionEvaluatingReleaseStrategy("size() == 5")
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponCompletion(true);
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression(new ValueExpression<>(3000L)); //size() ge 2 ? 5000 : -1
        aggregatingMessageHandler.setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(true);
        return aggregatingMessageHandler;
    }
```

To pass the message between aggregator and task launcher method (setupRequest(String message)) , i am using a channel **MyProcessor.intermidiate** defined as below

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Output;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.SubscribableChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Indexed;


public interface MyProcessor {
    String intermidiate = "intermidiate";

    @Output("intermidiate")
    MessageChannel intermidiate();

}
```

Applicaion.properties used is below

```
aggregator.message-store-type=persistentMessageStore
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=input
```

Its not working , With the above mentioned approach .

In this class if i change the channel name from my defined channel MyProcessor.intermediate to Processor.input or Processor.output than any one of the things works (based on the channel name changed to Processor.*)

I want to aggregate the messages first and than want to launch task on aggragated messages in processor, which is not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here:

```
public Object setupRequest(String message) {
```

So, you expect some `string` as a request payload.

Your `AggregatorFactoryBean` use a `DefaultAggregatingMessageGroupProcessor`, which does exactly this:

```
    List<Object> payloads = new ArrayList<Object>(messages.size());
    for (Message<?> message : messages) {
        payloads.add(message.getPayload());
    }
    return payloads;
```

So, it is definitely not a `String`.

It is strange that you don't show what exception happens with your configuration, but I assume you need to change `setupRequest()` signature to expect a `List` of payloads or you need to provide some custom `MessageGroupProcessor` to build that `String` from the group of messages you have aggregated.

Comment: I am not getting any exception... It looks like the aggregate method is called but the result of aggregate() method is not passed to setupRequest()  method and thats why i did'nt even get the exception for issue you mentioned. In Spring cloud stream how can i call two steps (like aggregation -> cloud task launch) in one processor.

Comment: Since `intermediate` channel is something internal to your application, you must not declare a binding for it. Please, remove that `MyProcessor` interface altogether